# Using XDomain object for IE8+ in Jquery

Tags: ajax, jquery, cross-domain, xdomainrequest

my skills with jquery core are not that great, though Ive been working with JQuery for almost a year now.So here is the question.

What changes would I need to do , if I want to use XDomainRequest whenever a cross-domain request is made on IE8+?

Basically, I want to make changes to the xhr function for jquery.ajaxSettings object, so that whenever a cross-domain request is made , and the browser is detected as IE8+, the xhr returns a XDR rather than an XHR.

What all pitfalls would I need to keep in mind before I do that?

Any other pointers that anyone would want to give are appreciated.

I know this as a question is very general, but from what I feel, so is the topic of substituting xhr with xdr in the required scenario.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should try the [AjaxHook](https://github.com/jaubourg/ajaxHooks) extension.

Answer (score 2):

JQuery doesn't support this natively, but you can hack around it yourself. Here's the original JQuery bug report about this issue:

http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/8283

That link above has some work around code. Here is a more complete solution:

https://github.com/jaubourg/ajaxHooks/blob/master/src/ajax/xdr.js